# JQuery Mobile Controlgroup Width

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm just getting my feet wet with jquery-mobile.....

I want to make a controlgroup that has a width of 100% and inside that group have a left button with 70% width and a right one with 30% but am having no luck. Here is what I've tried:  http://jsfiddle.net/bykB8/

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link : [**Info**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html)

It says :

***By adding the data-type="horizontal" attribute to the controlgroup container, you can swap to a horizontal-style group that floats the buttons side-by-side and sets the width to only be large enough to fit the content.***

So, if you want to re size, use `<a>` instead of `<buttons>` .
Then you can give your links styles.

Have a look at this fiddle : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bykB8/1/)

You will notice that the widths in this demo are `70%` and `29%` . Thats because both the buttons have border. And it covers some of their widths. And if you want to fit the width to `70%` and `30%,` set `border:none;` for both element. :)

[**Demo 70% and 30%**](http://jsfiddle.net/bykB8/2/)